# How to access Address Memory GPU C++AMP in MATLAB with mex?

Tags: matlab, visual-studio-2012, c++-amp

```
void mexFunction( int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],
                  int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[]) 
{
 extent<2> e(m, n);
 array_view<const float, 2> GPUmatrix(e,prhs[])
.
.
.
.

}
```

**i want access to  memory of GPU, with C++AMP in matlab**

I have radeon GPU with SP and DP compute_process, and I want use only a GPU, in my computing algorithm. ??? for avoid access to CPU memory.

Comment: Have you considered these approaches? http://www.cac.cornell.edu/matlab/TechDocs/Examples/BestPracticesGPU.aspx

Comment: **Thanks.** my card is AMD radeon.
I do not know from what, I can begin to implement the C++ AMP in matlab mex. Create GPUArray in C++ AMP ???? :)

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "I want use only a GPU, in my computing"? Do you want to keep the result on the GPU and avoid copying it back to the CPU memory? Would you want then to use the data in subsequent algorithm steps on the GPU? Can you also give more details what in the high-level scenario that you want to solve?

Comment: I need access to Memory GPU in matlab for computing same as CUDA GPUarray.  Not support other GPU only Nvidia in Matlab. Who create matrix(GPU) and access in **matlab with mex C++AMP** ?  thanks for your help :)